# Erro java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MainActivity.checkSelfPermission

Tags: java, android, android-permission

estou realizando varias tentativas, mas não consigo obter a localização atual de um usuario utilizando da Location API.

Estou executando o exemplo a seguir:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

Location localizacao;
GoogleApiClient mapGoogleApiClient;
EditText edtLat;
EditText edtLog;
Button btLocalizacao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edtLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLatitude);
    edtLog = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLongitude);
    btLocalizacao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLocalizacao);

    if (mapGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mapGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    btLocalizacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GPS();
        }
    });
}




@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void GPS() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    localizacao = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mapGoogleApiClient);
    if (localizacao != null) {
        edtLat.setText(String.valueOf(localizacao.getLatitude()));
        edtLog.setText(String.valueOf(localizacao.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        AlertDialog erroLocation = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        erroLocation.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
        erroLocation.setTitle("Localização não encontrada");
        erroLocation.setMessage("Sua Localização não foi encontrada!! Tente novamente!");
        erroLocation.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}}
```

Porem ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.estudosmobileoreia.mapsdemo.MainActivity.checkSelfPermission
```

Sabendo que o AndroidManifest.xml esta com as seguintes permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Gostaria de saber se alguem pode me auxiliar com esse erro ou demonstrar outra maneira de obter a localização do usuario ?

..Meu XML esta correto, tanto que nele existe somente um Button para obter a localização e 4 TextView para me retornar a localização em dois deles..

Comment: @ramaral o que eu precisaria retirar do método ? Pode comentar um exemplo, por favor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `checkSelfPermission(String permission)` não existe.

O método é declarado na classe *ContextCompat*, da qual descende ActivityCompat, com dois parâmetros: [checkSelfPermission(Context context, String permission)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) , altere para:

```
checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```